# PlatformIO Fatal Build Error: LiquidCrystal.h "No such file or directory"

Tags: build, compiler-errors, arduino, platformio, esp32

I'm fairly new to Atom / PlatformIO and tried using it for development with Arduino as an alternative to Arduino IDE.

~The Specs~

```
base code used: Arduino ESP sample code "WifiBlueToothSwitch.ino"
Board: ESP-WROOM-32
Additional Components: 1602A (2x16) LCD
```

---

I've successfully run other sample code on the ESP module through PlatformIO prior to attempting to use the LCD screen, however when I did attempt to include the LiquidCrystal.h library, it gives me a build error:

```
src\main.cpp:22:27: fatal error: LiquidCrystal.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
*** [.pioenvs\esp32dev\src\main.o] Error 1
[ERROR] Took 3.34 seconds
```

So of several of the sites I've searched about this issue so far, most point to the missing addition of the "wire.h" header file, however even after including it into the program, it still gives me this error.

My includes are as follows:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
```

So I'm not entirely sure why this problem is occurring. 
How can I resolve this issue?

---

Edit 1:

I came across another site a moment ago that suggested attempting an update of PlatformIO via console, however this was to no avail. Everything was marked as "Up-to-date".

```
Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\171031-143050-esp32dev> platformio update
Updating tool-scons                      @ 3.20501.2      [Up-to-date]
Updating tool-unity                      @ 1.20302.1      [Up-to-date]
Updating pysite-pioplus                  @ 0.4.2          [Up-to-date]
Updating contrib-piohome                 @ 0.3.1          [Up-to-date]
Updating tool-pioplus                    @ 0.10.11        [Up-to-date]

Platform Manager
================
Platform Espressif 32
--------
Updating espressif32                     @ 0.10.0         [Up-to-date]

Updating tool-esptoolpy                  @ 1.20000.0      [Up-to-date]
Updating toolchain-xtensa32              @ 1.50200.0      [Up-to-date]
Updating framework-arduinoespressif32    @ 1.2.0          [Up-to-date]
Updating tool-espotapy                   @ 1.0.0          [Up-to-date]


Library Manager
===============
Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\171031-143050-esp32dev>
```

---

Edit 2:

I *have* compiled and run this code through the Arduino IDE and can confirm that it works, so the problem seems to be with the PlatformIO IDE...

---

Edit 3:

After following BMelis's suggestion, I looked into the PlatformIO.ini file, and added the following line to it:

```
lib_extra_dirs = C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\espressif\esp32\libraries
```

This fixed the initial error for the LiquidCrystal.h, However this also produced the following dependency error during build:

```
[11/06/17 08:52:58] Processing esp32dev (platform: espressif32; lib_extra_dirs: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\espressif\esp32\libraries; board: esp32dev; framework: arduino)

Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
Collected 49 compatible libraries
Looking for dependencies...
Library Dependency Graph
|-- <WiFi> v1.0

|-- <Wire> v1.0
|-- <LiquidCrystal> v1.0.7
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32dev\lib\WiFi\WiFiAP.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32dev\lib\WiFi\WiFiGeneric.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32dev\lib\WiFi\WiFiMulti.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp32dev\lib\WiFi\WiFiSTA.o

****ERROR OCCURRED****
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\espressif\esp32\libraries\WiFi\src\WiFiAP.cpp:40:37: fatal error: apps/dhcpserver_options.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
*** [.pioenvs\esp32dev\lib\WiFi\WiFiAP.o] Error 1
 [ERROR] Took 8.13 seconds
```

I tried adding the directory that it was mentioning by adding a second lib_extra_dirs command in the ini file:

```
lib_extra_dirs = C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\espressif\esp32\tools\sdk\include\lwip\apps
```

However this did nothing to resolve the issue. I am at a loss as to what to do now...

---

FULL CODE:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
// Copyright 2015-2016 Espressif Systems (Shanghai) PTE LTD
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at

//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

// Sketch shows how to switch between WiFi and BlueTooth or use both
// Button is attached between GPIO 0 and GND and modes are switched with each press

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#define STA_SSID "HIDDEN FOR SECURITY"
#define STA_PASS "HIDDEN FOR SECURITY"
#define AP_SSID  "esp32 @ my desk"
#define LED_PIN  5

//LCD variables on analog inputs, but used as digital I/O
//lcd_gnd = gnd
//lcd_vcc = +5v
//lcd_v0 = +5v & pot
const int lcd_rs = 27;
//lcd_rw = gnd
const int lcd_e = 14;
//lcd_d0 = n/a
//lcd_d1 = n/a
//lcd_d2 = n/a
//lcd_d3 = n/a
const int lcd_d4 = 32;
const int lcd_d5 = 33;
const int lcd_d6 = 25;
const int lcd_d7 = 26;
//lcd_bl1 = +5v
//lcd_bl2 = gnd
LiquidCrystal lcd(lcd_rs, lcd_e, lcd_d4, lcd_d5, lcd_d6, lcd_d7);

enum { STEP_BTON, STEP_BTOFF, STEP_STA, STEP_AP, STEP_AP_STA, STEP_OFF, STEP_BT_STA, STEP_END };

void onButton(){
  static uint32_t step = STEP_BTON;
  switch(step){
    case STEP_BTON://BT Only
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("Starting BT");
      btStart();
    break;
    case STEP_BTOFF://All Off
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("Stopping BT");
      btStop();
    break;
    case STEP_STA://STA Only
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("Starting STA");
      WiFi.begin(STA_SSID, STA_PASS);
    break;
    case STEP_AP://AP Only
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("Stopping STA");
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);

      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("Starting AP");
      WiFi.softAP(AP_SSID);
    break;
    case STEP_AP_STA://AP+STA
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("Starting STA");
      WiFi.begin(STA_SSID, STA_PASS);
    break;
    case STEP_OFF://All Off
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("Stopping WiFi");
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
    break;
    case STEP_BT_STA://BT+STA
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("Starting STA+BT");
      WiFi.begin(STA_SSID, STA_PASS);
      btStart();
    break;
    case STEP_END://All Off
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("Stopping WiFi+BT");
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
      btStop();
    break;
    default:
    break;
  }
  if(step == STEP_END){
    step = STEP_BTON;
  } else {
    step++;
  }
  //little debounce
  delay(100);
}

void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event){
    switch(event) {
        case SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_START:
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
            lcd.print("AP Started");
            Serial.print("AP Started");
            WiFi.softAPsetHostname(AP_SSID);
            break;
        case SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STOP:
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
            lcd.print("AP Stopped");
            Serial.print("AP Stopped");
            break;
        case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_START:
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
            lcd.print("STA Started");
            Serial.print("STA Started");
            WiFi.setHostname(AP_SSID);
            break;
        case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_CONNECTED:
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
            lcd.print("STA Connected");
            Serial.print("STA Connected");
            WiFi.enableIpV6();
            break;
        case SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STA_GOT_IP6:
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
            lcd.print("STA IPv6: ");
            Serial.print("STA IPv6: ");
            Serial.println(WiFi.localIPv6());
            break;
        case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP:
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
            lcd.print("STA IPv4: ");
            Serial.print("STA IPv4: ");
            lcd.setCursor(0,1);
            lcd.print(WiFi.localIP());
            Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
            break;
        case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED:
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
            lcd.print("STA Disconnected");
            Serial.print("STA Disconnected");
            break;
        case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_STOP:
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
            lcd.print("STA Stopped");
            Serial.print("STA Stopped");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void setup() {
    lcd.begin(16, 2); //tells arduino that the LCD is a 16x2 size LCD
    lcd.clear(); //clear any previous text
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0); // set cursor to column 0 of row 0 (first row, first block)

    pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW); // LED off
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(0, INPUT_PULLUP);
    WiFi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);
    Serial.print("ESP32 SDK: ");
    Serial.println(ESP.getSdkVersion());
    Serial.println("Press the button to select the next mode");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.println("Press mode btn");
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); // Turn on LED
    static uint8_t lastPinState = 1;
    uint8_t pinState = digitalRead(0);
    if(!pinState && lastPinState){
        onButton();
    }
    lastPinState = pinState;
}
```

Comment: Pio can't find the file in the regular places. So you'll have to tell Pio to look elsewhere. You can define that in platformio.ini: [link](http://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf.html) (this is only one way to do this, there are others!) So where is this lib stored on your computer and what does your platformio.ini file looks like?

Comment: @BMelis Thanks for the information! I am still very new to Platform and Atom, so I thought that a standard library such as LiquidCrystal.h would have been included by default. I will update the path and let you know if this works.

Comment: @BMelis Sorry for the delay, I caught a rather nasty cold and was recovering for the last few days. Unfortunately, I am still receiving issues regarding this error, despite adding the library paths to the .ini file. The issue i'm getting now, however is this:  

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\espressif\esp32\libraries\WiFi\src\WiFiAP.cpp:40:37: fatal error: apps/dhcpserver_options.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
*** [.pioenvs\esp32dev\lib\WiFi\WiFiAP.o] Error 1`

Comment: I updated the OP ^ with further details of the new issue. This seems to be a dependency issue of the WiFi library, however adding the path to the dependency folder did nothing... (See "Edit 3" above)

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal type:

```
pio lib install "LiquidCrystal"
```

Answer (score 0):

For platformio, I work this way (I'm on Win10):
All my projects are in "my documents". General purpose libraries are in "my documents/libraries". Specific ones reside in the "lib" folder of the pio project.

In platformio.ini I have for example the following:

```
[env:lolin32]
;platform = espressif32
platform = https://github.com/platformio/platform-espressif32.git#feature/stage
board = lolin32
framework = arduino
lib_extra_dirs = ..\libraries
lib_deps = 
  https://urltotherepo.git
```

for the platform you can comment out the right one (stage or release but for Arduino ESP32 "release" is quite...unstable)

put the right path in lib_extra_dirs and try to keep away from hiding all the libraries in the "Program Files" folder as it is quite unhandy to change something there if needed.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try and let you know if it works for me. I will start clean with a new project file, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to download the **LiquidCrystal** package or isntall it with PlatformIO CLI. Check this: http://platformio.org/lib/show/887/LiquidCrystal/installation

Copy unzipped LiquidCrystal folder int your project's `/lib` folder please and try to build again.

ps: Private/3rd party libraries should be placed `/lib` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem as well.  I believe the best solution is to add the entry to your `platformio.ini` file for the project and board(s).  That way you don't need to add the library code to your own source tree, and this solution is resilient against 'works on my computer' as the project doesn't rely on the library being somewhere specific on your file system.  Note I targeted a specific version here for maximum predictability, but you don't have to.

```
[env:nanoatmega328]
platform = atmelavr
board = nanoatmega328
framework = arduino
lib_deps = LiquidCrystal@1.5.0 #<--important line
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually add liquidcrystal library to PlatformIO and this resolved it for me with the following steps:

1. Go to to PIO Home
2. Click on 'Libraries' below the reload home button
3. Search for and select liquidcrystal by arduino
4. Click add to project